# CSS Design: Three Divs

Tags: css, html, background, footer

I want to arrange "leftbox" "midbox" and "rightbox" divs next to each other.
When i used float:left, my footer goes to top.

Anyone can help me, so i can make them arrange next  to each other and still my footer is in the lower part.

anyone would like to change my codes so it will become smaller in size.

here is my codes.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
XXX
</title>
</head>
<style>
body{
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
background-color:#dedede;
}
#header{
 background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(241, 241, 241);
    background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: auto auto;
    height: 31px;
    position:fixed;
    //position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 985;
    min-width: 980px;
}
#header2{
 background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(241, 241, 241);
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    height: 71px;
    position:fixed;
    //position:relative;
    top: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 985;
    min-width: 980px;
}
#wrapper{
position:relative;
width:980px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
}
#logo{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:10px;
width:102px;
height:60px;
font:68px Blue Highway;
color:#01b5ce;
}
#logo:hover{
color:#aaaaaf;
}
#navigation{
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:170px;
width:auto;
height:40px;
}
#navigation a{
position:relative;
top:20px;
width:auto;
height:30px;
font:18px Corbel;
margin-left:5px;
border-left:1px solid #dddddd;
text-decoration:none;
color:#aaaaaf;
}
#navigation a:hover{
color:#01b5ce;
}
#access{
position:absolute;
top:5px;
right:10px;
width:auto;
height:20px;
}
#access a{
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
color:#01b5ce;
font:18px Corbel;
margin-left:10px;
}
#body{
position:relative;
top:100px;
width:980px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
background-color:#ffffff;
}
    #leftbox{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:160px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:red;
    }
    #ads{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    width:160px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:green;
    }
    #midbox{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:red;
    }
    #latest{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:green;
    }
    #rightbox{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:280px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:red;
    }
    #top{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    width:280px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:green;
    }
    .title{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:yellow;
    font:20px WLM Carton;
    color:#cc0000;
    }

#footer{
 background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #444444;
    background-color: #444444;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: auto auto;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 105px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 985;
    min-width: 980px;
}
#footerContent{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    margin:auto;
    width:980px;
    height:80px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font: 12px Arial,tahoma;
}
#ads ul{ list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; width:390px; height:auto;}
#ads ul li{ padding:5px; margin:0; width:390px; height:auto; float:left;}

#latest ul{ list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; width:390px; height:auto;}
#latest ul li{ padding:5px; margin:0; width:390px; height:auto; float:left;}
#latest #wrapper{width:490px; height:auto; float:left; color: #7a7a7a;text-align: left; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
#latest #date{background-color:#f3f3f3; border-top:1px solid #b6b6b6; border-left:1px solid #b6b6b6; border-right:1px solid #b6b6b6; border-bottom:1px solid #b6b6b6; width:70px; height:60px; float:left;}
#latest #content{ float:left; width: 405px; height:auto; margin: 0 0 0 10px;}

#top ul{ list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; width:390px; height:auto;}
#top ul li{ padding:5px; margin:0; width:390px; height:auto; float:left;}
</style>
<body>
<div id=header>
    <div id=wrapper>
        <div id=access>
            <a href=''>Register</a>
            <a href=''>Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=header2>
    <div id=wrapper>
        <div id=logo>
            <b><font color='#aaaaaf'>X</font>XXX</b>
        </div>
        <div id=navigation>
            <a href=''>&nbsp;X</a>
            <a href=''>&nbsp;X</a>
            <a href=''>&nbsp;X</a>
            <a href=''>&nbsp;X</a>
            <a href=''>&nbsp;X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=body>
    <div id=leftbox>
        <div id=ads>
            <div class=title>
            ADS
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=''><img src='' width=160 height=180></a></li>
                <li><a href=''><img src='' width=160 height=180></a></li>
                <li><a href=''><img src='' width=160 height=180></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id=midbox>
        <div id=latest>
            <div class=title>
            Latest Album
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div id='wrapper'>
                        <div id='date'>
                            <div class=month><b>JAN</b></div>
                            <div class=day>01 2013</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id='content'>
                            <b>Happy New Year!</b>
                            <br>
                            Wishing you all the blessings of the New Year...the warmth of home, the love of family and the company of good friends.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id=rightbox>
        <div id=top>
            <div class=title>
            Featured DJs
            </div>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div id=footer>
    <div id=footerContent>
        <center>
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

        <br><br>
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common problem my friend!

When we float elements, it's hard for the parent element to keep track on their height. In order for the parent element to know it's children height, we append a "clearfix".

**CSS**

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Then, append that element on the same level of your float elements.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>

    <!-- lets clear this shizzle -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: so thanks.. now i know what is the use of clear.. i have a friend gave me some samples for this.. but..  i cant  do it because i dont have clearfix in my codes.. but now i know .. :) thankd man..

Comment: Hello from the future! We now have various clearfix technics based on pseudo-elements, so there is no need to use crappy markup.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I am aware of that. But I dont want to fail serving my webpages to a surprisingly large group of people who have older browsers. Pseudo-elements are cool, but using those would leave a lot of people with weird looking pages. That is why I prefer accessibility over "crappy markup". In real life situations it just happens too often customers complain about compatibility with older browsers. I guess that comes with experience.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

`#footer{ clear: both; }`

and everything will be hunky dory; no need to add a [non-semantic] clearer div.

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBH9M/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">

    </div>
    <div id="center">

    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left, #right, #center{

    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30%;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read this w3 article on flow-control it will help you understand why triggers elements position and why http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control.

Adding elements into the documents will have an effect on flow, especially when the screen is resized, rotated etc.

Just add **style="clear:both"** inline to your footer as